# How to retrieve url params or session object from jsp to reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, jsp, react-redux

We have one application in ps framework (jsp file page). In that I have selected one account number for the particular member Id. After that I have to choose one option from the dropdown. It will popup new window which is react and redux application for a second and it is logged out. In this application I have to get the logged member id and the selected account number from that popup file. I can able to see in network tab of chrome browser as url with params of selected account and member number. But i cannot able to get back in react redux application. How can we aceive this to display selected account and member number. Give me example.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: Anyway, the key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.